# How to make a log plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Is it possible to make a plot in matlab that does not actually take the logs of the values? I'm plotting wide ranges of values and when I try to make a log plot of them, those below 1 become negative. I would just like it to plot the values on a log scale without taking their logs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use [the `loglog` command](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/loglog.html).

The example from the Mathworks website:

```
x = logspace(-1,2);   % generate a sequence of points equally spaced logarithmically
loglog(x,exp(x),'-s')
grid on
```

[image]

If you do not want both axes to be log scale, use [`semilogx` or `semilogy`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/semilogx.html).

Answer (score 22):

Alternatively, set(gca,'XScale','log') if you have your plot already.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to plot **liner** data on **logarithmic** axes? You can exponentiate you values before using the log plot. This way the point p=(10,3) will plot at the x=10 position.