# Plot Cumulative Distribution Function (logarithmic x-axis / y-axis) in MatLab

Tags: matlab, statistics

I was using `cdfplot`, but it doesn't work as I need.
How can I get the x-axis become logarithmic? and how can I do it for y-axis?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a log plot in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454513/how-to-make-a-log-plot-in-matlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by looking into handle graphics. Just run this code after you run cdfplot:

```
set(gca,'XScale','log')
```

What it does: it gets the axis handle (`gca`/get current axis) and sets it's XScale property. To know what properties are available, you can either consult the help or run `inspect(gca)`.

You can also do the same thing manually on a single plot, to do this, you just plot everything and in the Figure window use the Tools > Edit Plot option. Then double click on the axis and you can set most properties right there.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is great in that you not only answered but also helps me solve problems in the future!