# semilogy, loglog do not work in order to set the y axis on a logarithmic scale

Tags: matlab, plot

I am working on a numerical algorithm and I want to plot the error for 5 different shape parameters of my function. I want all the plots to figure on one same figure.

Here is the code that I use:

```
figure
hold on
for i=3:7
    [coord_ctrs, errors] = ApproxAdap1D(i);
    
    semilogy(coord_ctrs, (errors));
    title("Senkung des RMS Fehlers");
grid;
end
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, it does not work, the y axis does not  have a logarithmic scale. loglog function displays tthe same result too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `figure; hold on`; that creates a linear figure, and you're adding subsequent plots to the linear axes.

You should set the axis to log explicitly.

Following on from [How to make a log plot in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454513/how-to-make-a-log-plot-in-matlab/3455173#3455173)

`set(gca,'XScale','log')`

Comment: I called hold on after smilogy and it worked, thank you!